# How to get string without /n/t when you do gettext in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have my code like this

```
<a href="/trade/view/92204">
                        2008 Honda Odyssey - 5dr Wgn EX-L
                    </a
```

when I do gettext returns the following string
"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2008 Honda Odyssey - 5dr Wgn EX-L\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"

I use partial link text to click on the link, but it says Element not found.

How can I get rid of this /n/t

Comment: Try using String.trim() to remove trailing whitespace.

Comment: Does the getText() return "\n" and "\t" in the output, for real ? Or, have you added them to represent the question in a better way ? Because, these escape characters do not come up in the output while retrieving text using getText(). Hence, just confirming,, :)

Answer (score 1):

well, you can just remove them from the string

```
String s = "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2008 Honda Odyssey - 5dr Wgn EX-L\n\t\t\t\t\t\t" //gettext... how ever u get your string

s=s.replaceAll("\n","").replaceAll("\t","");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `String.trim()` method. Something like:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));  // adjust as appropriate
String s = el.getText();
assert s.trim().equals("2008 Honda Odyssey - 5dr Wgn EX-L");
```

You can read all about it in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html).